# Documentation for Geoserver XML

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to use Geoserver's RESTful API within limited success. I've found the [REST API's documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/index.html), but what I seem to be missing is the documentation that outlines the XML/JSON interface. From what I gather, there is a whole XML/JSON interface that is used for GET'ing/POST'ing new constructs, such as workspaces, data stores, layers, etc... [Here are plenty of examples](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html)

Is there other documentation that fully outlines this XML? The above examples are great, but I'm having a hard time extrapolating from these examples. A complete interface documentation (like the REST API) would be helpful.

Comment: What I've found useful so far is to try to mimic the XML created in the Geoserver "data" directory after first creating a construct via the web interface. E.g. Create a coverage store via web interface, understand the XML created in the data directory, and then attempt to use the REST API to post a modified version of the XML.

Comment: But restful interfaces are self documenting :-) just ask for an example of any object from the server, the put it back

Comment: Also documentation pull requests are always well received.